# Antlr v4: What's wrong with this simple grammar for C# literals?

Tags: c#, antlr

I decided to translate the C# official grammar to **antlr v4**. However, while testing I encountered the following problem. The given grammar doesn't match simple words like `\n\ntrue\n\n<EOF>`. It keeps saying `mismatched input '\n\ntrue\n\n' expecting Literal`
. Even after I leave the definition of `Literal` as `Literal: BooleanLiteral;` the input `\n\ntrue\n\n<EOF>` still doesn't get matched. I was expecting the grammar to skip the `\n`s comsume the `true` and `<EOF>` but obviously this is not happening. Tried to debug but still haven't be able to find anything wrong. Any ideas?

```
grammar Test;

start: Literal EOF;

/**********
 *
 * Literals
 *
 **********/

Literal
    :   BooleanLiteral 
    |   IntegerLiteral 
    |   RealLiteral 
    |   CharacterLiteral 
    |   StringLiteral 
    |   NullLiteral 
    ;

BooleanLiteral
    :   'true' 
    |   'false' 
    ;

IntegerLiteral
    :   DecimalIntegerLiteral 
    |   HexadecimalIntegerLiteral 
    ;

DecimalIntegerLiteral
    :   DecimalDigits IntegerTypeSuffix? 
    ;

DecimalDigits
    :   DecimalDigit+
    ;

DecimalDigit
    :   [0-9]
    ;

IntegerTypeSuffix
    :   'U' 
    |   'u' 
    |   'L' 
    |   'l' 
    |   'UL' 
    |   'Ul' 
    |   'uL' 
    |   'ul' 
    |   'LU' 
    |   'Lu' 
    |   'lU' 
    |   'lu' 
    ;

HexadecimalIntegerLiteral
    :   ('0x' | '0X') HexDigits IntegerTypeSuffix?
    ;

HexDigits
    :   HexDigit+
    ;

HexDigit    
    :   [0-9A-Fa-f]
    ;

RealLiteral
    :   DecimalDigits '.' DecimalDigits ExponentPart? RealTypeSuffix? 
    |   '.' DecimalDigits ExponentPart? RealTypeSuffix? 
    |   DecimalDigits ExponentPart RealTypeSuffix? 
    |   DecimalDigits RealTypeSuffix 
    ;

ExponentPart
    :   ('e' | 'E') Sign? DecimalDigits
    ;

Sign    
    :   '+'
    |   '-' 
    ;

RealTypeSuffix  
    :   'F'
    |   'f' 
    |   'D' 
    |   'd' 
    |   'M' 
    |   'm' 
    ;

CharacterLiteral
    :   '\'' Character '\'' 
    ;

Character
    :   SingleCharacter 
    |   SimpleEscapeSequence 
    |   HexadecimalEscapeSequence 
    |   UnicodeEscapeSequence 
    ;

UnicodeEscapeSequence
    :   '\\' 'u' HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit 
    |   '\\' 'U' HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit 
    ;

SingleCharacter
    :   ~[\\\\\\\u000D\u000A\u0085\u2028\u2029]
    ;

SimpleEscapeSequence    
    : '\\\''
    | '\\"'
    | '\\\\'
    | '\\0'
    | '\\a'
    | '\\b'
    | '\\f'
    | '\\n'
    | '\\r'
    | '\\t'
    | '\\v'
    ;

HexadecimalEscapeSequence
    :   '\\x' HexDigit HexDigit? HexDigit? HexDigit? 
    ;

StringLiteral
    :   RegularStringLiteral 
    |   VerbatimStringLiteral 
    ;

RegularStringLiteral
    :   '"' RegularStringLiteralCharacters? '"' 
    ;

RegularStringLiteralCharacters
    :   RegularStringLiteralCharacter+
    ;

RegularStringLiteralCharacter
    :   SingleRegularStringLiteralCharacter 
    |   SimpleEscapeSequence 
    |   HexadecimalEscapeSequence 
    |   UnicodeEscapeSequence 
    ;

SingleRegularStringLiteralCharacter
    :   ~["\\\u000D\u000A\u0085\u2028\u2029]
    ;

VerbatimStringLiteral
    :   '@"' VerbatimStringLiteralCharacters? '"' 
    ;

VerbatimStringLiteralCharacters
    :   VerbatimStringLiteralCharacter+
    ;

VerbatimStringLiteralCharacter
    :   SingleVerbatimStringLiteralCharacter 
    |   QuoteEscapeSequence 
    ;

SingleVerbatimStringLiteralCharacter
    :   ~["]
    ;

QuoteEscapeSequence
    :   '""' 
    ;

NullLiteral
    :   'null'
    ;


/**********
 *
 * Whitespaces and comments
 *
 **********/    

WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
    ;

COMMENT
    :   '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip
    ;

LINE_COMMENT
    :   '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip
    ;
```

EDIT:
Ok, I've managed to isolate the problem to this piece of code:

```
grammar Test;

start : VerbatimStringLiteral EOF ;

VerbatimStringLiteral
    :   '@"' VerbatimStringLiteralCharacter* '"' 
    ;

VerbatimStringLiteralCharacter
    :   SingleVerbatimStringLiteralCharacter 
    |   QuoteEscapeSequence 
    ;

SingleVerbatimStringLiteralCharacter
    :   ~["]
    ;

QuoteEscapeSequence
    :   '""' 
    ;

WS  :  [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lexer rules which do not produce tokens themselves should be marked with the `fragment` modifier. For example, `QuoteEscapeSequence` is not a standalone token; it is just a part of the `VerbatimStringLiteral` token, so you should mark it with `fragment`. Here are some other rules which should be `fragment` rules:

- `VerbatimStringLiteralCharacter`
- `SingleVerbatimStringLiteralCharacter`
- `SingleRegularStringLiteralCharacter`
- `RegularStringLiteralCharacter`
- `RegularStringLiteralCharacters` ← this one was the source of your errors for this particular input
- `SimpleEscapeSequence`

There may be more, but this should give you an idea what the problem is and how to solve it.

Comment: Ok, thx but isn't it possible for `antlr` to detect which which rules should be fragments and label them automatically? If not is there a possible algorithm?

Comment: In some cases, a rule can be a token on its own and is also referenced as a part of another token. The algorithm you describe would either break that functionality or make it very confusing.